# Cannot Install TFS agent on Window Server 2012 R2, unclear error

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

Agent Version: 2.122.1
Windows -Windows server 2012 R2, TFS version -2017, getting this error when trying to install TFS agent on windows, exits when i run run.cmd from TFS agent folder. the installer exits with these errors. There seems to be no clear documentation of troubleshooting such errors. the power shell version on the machine is 4.0.

```
Agent is built for Windows - win7-x64.
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO AgentProcess] RuntimeInformation: Microsoft 
Windows 6.3.9600 .
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO AgentProcess] Version: 2.122.1
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO AgentProcess] Commit: 
fc6746af2429c6ffa73c0793d732e6853f9fb375
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO AgentProcess] Culture: en-US
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO AgentProcess] UI Culture: en-US
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': 'C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool\bin'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Root': 'C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO AgentProcess] Validating directory permissions for: 'C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO PowerShellExeUtil] Generation: '1'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO PowerShellExeUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1', value name 'Install': '1'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO PowerShellExeUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\PowerShellEngine', value name 'PowerShellVersion': '2.0'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO PowerShellExeUtil] Unsupported version. Skipping.
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO PowerShellExeUtil] Generation: '3'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO PowerShellExeUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3', value name 'Install': '1'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO PowerShellExeUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine', value name 'PowerShellVersion': '4.0'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO PowerShellExeUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\PowerShellEngine', value name 'ApplicationBase': 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework', value name 'InstallRoot': 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP' contains sub keys:
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil]  'CDF'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil]  'v3.0'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil]  'v4'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil]  'v4.0'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0', value name 'Version' is null.
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0', value name '' is null.
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0' contains sub keys:
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil]  'Setup'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.0\Setup', value name 'Version' is null.
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4', value name 'Version' is null.
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4', value name '' is null.
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4' contains sub keys:
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil]  'Client'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil]  'Full'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client', value name 'Version': '4.7.03062'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client', value name 'Install': '1'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client', value name 'InstallPath': 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client', value name 'Release': '461814'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Type is System.Int32
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Interpreted version: 4.6.2
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', value name 'Version': '4.7.03062'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', value name 'Install': '1'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', value name 'InstallPath': 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full', value name 'Release': '461814'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Type is System.Int32
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Interpreted version: 4.6.2
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0', value name 'Version' is null.
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Key name 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4.0', value name '': 'deprecated'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Found 2 versions:
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil]  4.6.2
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil]  4.6.2
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO NetFrameworkUtil] Testing for min NET Framework version: '4.5'
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO CommandLineParser] Parse
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO CommandLineParser] Parsing 1 args
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO CommandLineParser] parsing argument
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO CommandLineParser] HasArgs: False
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO CommandLineParser] Adding Command: run
[2018-07-23 17:27:42Z INFO AgentProcess] Arguments parsed
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO VstsAgentWebProxy] No proxy setting found.
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO Agent] ExecuteCommand
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO ConfigurationStore] currentAssemblyLocation: C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool\bin\Agent.Listener.dll
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': 'C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool\bin'
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO ConfigurationStore] binPath: C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool\bin
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Bin': 'C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool\bin'
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO HostContext] Well known directory 'Root': 'C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool'
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO ConfigurationStore] RootFolder: C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO ConfigurationStore] ConfigFilePath: C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool\.agent
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO ConfigurationStore] CredFilePath: C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool\.credentials
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO ConfigurationStore] ServiceConfigFilePath: C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool\.service
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO ConfigurationStore] AutoLogonSettingsFilePath: C:\Users\SChalla\Downloads\CATTSPool\.autologon
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'help': 'False'
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'version': 'False'
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO CommandSettings] Flag 'commit': 'False'
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO CommandSettings] Command 'configure': 'False'
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO CommandSettings] Command 'remove': 'False'
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO CommandSettings] Command 'localRun': 'False'
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO ConfigurationManager] LoadSettings
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO ConfigurationStore] IsConfigured()
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO ConfigurationStore] IsConfigured: False
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z INFO ConfigurationManager] Is configured: False
[2018-07-23 17:27:43Z ERR  Terminal] WRITE ERROR: An error occurred: Not configured
[2018-07-23 17:27:44Z ERR  AgentProcess] System.InvalidOperationException: Not configured
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.LoadSettings()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Agent.<ExecuteCommand>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Listener.Program.<MainAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you the agent isn't configured.

Before you run the agent, you have to configure it with `configure.cmd`.